# Divisibility of term in exponential recurrence relation

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, divisibility

I found the problem here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1314296_2x15_is_divisible_by_x

$\large a_1 = 3$

$\large a_{n+1} = 2^{a_n -1} +5$

Prove:

$\large a_n|a_{n+1}$

Initially I tried inducting but found no way to make the statement carry on to the next recurrence.

This problem seems fairly interesting and I wonder if it can be done using elementary means.

The first four values of $a_n$ are as follows:

$3, 9, 261,$

$1852673427797059126777135760139006525652319754650249024631321344126610074238981$

Mathematica verifies the divisibility of $a_4$ by $a_3$, so the statement does appear to hold water.

Comment: Mathematica also verifies (using `PowerMod`) that $a_4\mid a_5$.

Comment: Fiddling around with this function.  $a_n$ is always odd because its is $2^n + 5 $.  It will also be divisible by 3 because $2^n mod 3$ is 1 when n is even.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/251717/iterations-of-2n-15-the-strong-law-of-small-numbers-or-something-bigger for extensive discussion.